# Error in jQuery ajax method and the page get refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
    $('.cn').click(function() {
        var pic_id = $(this).attr('href');
         console.log(pic_id);
        //alert(pic_id);

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>anda/coins",
            async: false,
            data: "pic_id="+pic_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                $('.cn_point').html(data.id);
            }
          });

        });
```

I got the call back value and showing on  but page gets refresh and value of span hide. is there anybody can help me ?I m unable to find my mistake .

Comment: Put `return false;` right after the `$.ajax` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `preventDefault`:

```
$('.cn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pic_id = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(pic_id);
    //alert(pic_id);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "<?php echo base_url();?>anda/coins",
        async : false,
        data : "pic_id=" + pic_id,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            $('.cn_point').html(data.id);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @DebendraSamal Show that by accepting this answer; click the outlined checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are clicking on the link and it would always refresh your page.

```
$('.cn').click(function() {

   e.preventDefault();
    var pic_id = $(this).attr('href');
     console.log(pic_id);
    //alert(pic_id);

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>anda/coins",
        async: false,
        data: "pic_id="+pic_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $('.cn_point').html(data.id);
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: That is not the issue and this won't solve the page refresh problem

Comment: You just copied what I posted before! XD

Comment: I did not copy your answer. I reviewed my answer and i noticed my mistake because i didnt read the last part of his question. You didnt tell him the reason why its behaving like this. I just explained him why its refreshing his page. So you can guess from that that i didnt copy your code. I modified his code.